# Provide two different instances of the same type

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, dagger

I have a Dagger module with two `@Provides` methods that construct different `Retrofit` instances. I also have two methods that each need to consume one of the `Retrofit` instances.

How do I tell Dagger which `Retrofit` I want to use in each of the consuming functions?

My code :

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(){
    final OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        builder.addInterceptor(logging);
    }

    builder.connectTimeout(60 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    return builder.build();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public Retrofit provideRestAdapter1(Application application, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder();
    builder.client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl(application.getString(R.string.Endpoint1))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    return builder.build();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public Retrofit provideRestAdapter2(Application application, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder();
    builder.client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl(application.getString(R.string.Endpoint2))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    return builder.build();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public GithubApiService provideGithubApiService(Retrofit restAdapter) {
    return restAdapter.create(GithubApiService.class);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public GithubApiService2 provideGithubApiService(Retrofit restAdapter) {
    return restAdapter.create(GithubApiService2.class);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@Qualifier` annotations to distinguish between the two.

First create a new annotation type (in its own java file of course):

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EndPoint1 {

}
```

Then annotate the relevant `@Provides` method:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@EndPoint1
public Retrofit provideRestAdapter1(Application application, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
    ...
}
```

And then tell Retrofit to use this one in the other `@Provides`:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public GithubApiService provideGithubApiService(@EndPoint1 Retrofit restAdapter) {
    return restAdapter.create(GithubApiService.class);
}
```

You can also use `@Named` if you don't want to create you own annotations. [See the documentation here](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide#qualifiers).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use name parameter

use this code

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("Google")
Retrofit providePlaceApiClient(OkHttpClient client, Gson gson) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BaseApiConfig.getPlaceApiUrl())
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient client, Gson gson) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BaseApiConfig.getBaseUrl())
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

You can get this using named annotation with inject annotation.

```
@Inject
@Named("Google")
Retrofit retrofit
```

Also, you can add on your component for child referance

```
@Named("Google")
Retrofit providePlaceApiClient();
```